# UBUNTU 16.04 I-tec DisplayLink Adapter

Tags: 16.04, adapter, displaylink

I have little problem to make DisplayLink work correctly. When I moving mouse my all screens lagging. Selected prime is Intel on Nvidia DisplayLink not working. On Windows it works perfect. 1 laptop screen and 1 monitor connected with HDMI not lagging. 1 Monitor little bit lagging connected with USB (DisplayPort) it is OK for me. But on Linux Lagging all of them... When i disconnect USB monitor it works with no lag... So it is possible to make it work correctly?

I tried change data in the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file, but what i changed it is not working. Maybe I don't know how to configurate it. Hmm.... I thinking it is possible to make one monitor work with Nvidia and others to intel?

Comment: Have you installed DisplayLink drivers?

Comment: Yes, I installed it.

Comment: The latest version 1.3.52 (if other try updating before anything else) shouldn't have such issues and it should work with Nvidia as well. Please edit your question and post the hardware information regarding both graphics.